# Question about widget landscape and portrait

Tags: mobile, unreal-engine4, unreal-umg

I need to use my menu with image in landscape and portrat (if user turns the phone to another position) using widget.

I need for landscape and portrait with different widget design, or exists other better solution (like works responsive html)?

Answer (score 0):

You can design your widgets for multiple resolutions using the canvas scaling (see [here](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/Engine/UMG/UserGuide/DPIScaling/index.html)) or by creating dedicated widgets for landscape and portrait. To determine which to show, simply compare the Screen width and height (see [here](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/BlueprintAPI/HUD/GetViewportSize/index.html)). If width > height, show the landscape and portrait elsewise.